# how to creat a button in ListView to play music

Tags: android

I have a problem in this adapter with play Button, please help me and thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this "currentSongs"

Comment: it's a model "songs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initalize media player first before use

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Then use it

```
 mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,currentSongs.getAudioResourceId());
```

Comment: The problem is still there. Thank you for your help

Comment: is that same error. can you provide that sound adapter code with this segment

Comment: I will try again and tell you the result

Comment: nice to hear it. happy coding